# Windows: user without home directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm automating the process of setting up a service on windows and one of the steps involves creating an account that can be configured as the "Log on as" user for the service.

My script currently has a problem where every time a new user is created in the machine a home directory gets created under /Users/%account%

This account does not need a home directory. Also, the script may run more than once in a machine and the account may be replaced, so I don't want a home directory structure to be created every time.

Is there a way to tell Windows that it shouldn't create a Home directory for the account?

Comment: It's certainly possible - see http://serverfault.com/questions/323947/how-to-create-a-user-without-a-profile-on-windows-7  I don't know off-hand how to automate it, but maybe serverfault would be a better forum?

Comment: @Joe, this will not avoid the profile creation, just will reduce the visibility of the account existence. But i agree with you, serverfault is a better option.

Answer (score 2):

The %account% folder you see in your `\users` folder is not exactly a *home directory*, but a *profile directory*. It is the place where are saved the files (NTUser.dat) that store the registry hives for the `CURRENT_USER` registry branches and all the configuration for the user. Every account needs a profile and if not present, it will be created on logon from the default user profile.

So, you have two options:

- use one of the already present service accounts (local system, local service or network service). You will not avoid the presence of a profile, but will reuse the present ones
- use a virtual account defining the account in the service configuration LogOn tab as `NT SERVICE\nameOfYourService`

See  [Service Accounts Step-by-Step Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548356%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for more information

Comment: First of all, thank you for the information. I didn't know about Virtual Accounts.

I've been reading through the article and the only issue I see is that they are only available starting since Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7, which doesn't include some of my target environments (Windows 7 and Windows Server 2003).

Comment: Just for the sake of completion, do you know if Virtual Accounts have administrator rights? I couldn't find any mention of it in the article. It would make sense that they didn't.

Cheers!

Comment: @user3505258, the virtual accounts will have the rights you give to them. This accounts does not show in the rights dialogs, but you can type the full name (`NT SERVICE\nameOfYourService`) and it will work.